# Testing for even letters, why does indexing differ inside and outside my function?

Tags: python, function, indexing

The function:

```
def func(word):
    out=[]
    for i in word:
        if i in word[0::2]:
            out.append(i.upper())
    return out
```

If I run

```
func('This is a string')
```

This returns:

```
['T','I','S', ' ', 'I','S', ' ','A', ' ','S','R','I','N']
```

which is what I expected when testing for every second letter from position 0.

Whereas

```
mystring = 'This is a string'
mystring[0::2]
```

Will return

```
'Ti sasrn'
```

Please note the function is not my production code but a point of interest that I found and simplified.

Comment: `if i in word[0::2]` checks if the current character is any one of the characters `'Ti sasrn'`. The result reflects that just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `for i in word:` outside the function. Your loop tests **every letter**, and there are repeated letters (and spaces) in your `mystring` value. You are not testing if their index is even.

Put differently, `mystring[0::2]` is used as the *set* of letters to include in the result, it is not the result itself, and Python doesn't keep track of what indices they came from.

You perhaps expected `if i in word[0::2]:` to take the position in `word` of the letter in `i` into account. If so, that's where your understanding is incorrect; `for i in word:` sets `i` to a single-character string (starting with `'T'`, then `'h'`, then `'i'`, then `'s'`, etc.) but there is no relationship between `i = 's'` it's original location in `word` any more. That `'s'` came from position `3` in `word` *doesn't matter and is not recorded*, only that `word[0::2]` contains the value `'s'` *as well*. Note that `word[0::2]` is also *just* a string, the `' '` space character in it is just a space character, Python has not recorded that it came from position 4 in `word` originally.

Let's examine what happens in the function, step by step. Given the input `'This is a string'`, the result of `word[0::2]` is `'Ti sasrn'`, so the values `'T'`, `'i'`, `' '`, `'s'`, `'a'`, `'r'` and `'n'` are all contained in it (with `'s'` contained *twice*). Then the outcome for the `if i in word[0::2]:` test in the loop, for each letter, is:

- `i = 'T'`, `'T' in word[0::2]` is true, `'T'` is added.
- `i = 'h'`, `'h' in word[0::2]` is false.
- `i = 'i'`, `'i' in word[0::2]` is true, `'I'` is added.
- `i = 's'`, `'s' in word[0::2]` is true, `'S'` is added.
- `i = ' '`, `' ' in word[0::2]` is true, `' '` is added.
- `i = 'i'`, `'i' in word[0::2]` is true, `'I'` is added.
- `i = 's'`, `'s' in word[0::2]` is true, `'S'` is added.
- `i = ' '`, `' ' in word[0::2]` is true, `' '` is added.
- `i = 'a'`, `'a' in word[0::2]` is true, `'A'` is added.
- `i = ' '`, `' ' in word[0::2]` is true, `' '` is added.
- `i = 's'`, `'s' in word[0::2]` is true, `'S'` is added.
- `i = 't'`, `'t' in word[0::2]` is false, case matters!
- `i = 'r'`, `'r' in word[0::2]` is true, `'T'` is added.
- `i = 'i'`, `'i' in word[0::2]` is true, `'I'` is added.
- `i = 'n'`, `'n' in word[0::2]` is true, `'N'` is added.
- `i = 'g'`, `'g' in word[0::2]` is false.

Together, that makes `out` contain `['T','I','S', ' ', 'I','S', ' ','A', ' ','S','R','I','N']`.

Note that the value `'t'` from the word `string` is *not* in the output, because `'t'` is not equal to `'T'`, which *is* in the `word[0::2]` result. Case matters when testing for string equality.

If you wanted to test if a letter is at an even position, you need to add a position counter to your loop. The [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) can do this for you:

```
for pos, letter in enumerate(word):
    if pos % 2 == 0:  # an even position
        out.append(letter.upper())
```

`enumerate()` gives you a `(counter, value)` tuple at every step, and so now you *do* know the position of every letter and can test if it is even.

or, you could just use `return word[::2].upper()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in word:
      if i in word[0::2]:
           out.append(i.upper())
```

This code iterates through the characters, and if some character is present in an even position, it adds it to the `out` list (even if the character being evaluated is in an odd position).

`func('abb')` will yield `[a, b, b]`, because when the second `b` is being evaluated, the function asks "is the letter `b` present in an even position in my string?", and since the answer is yes, it gets appended to the output.